# Query 100Gb of S3 data in milliseconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I have json data in s3. data looks like

```
{

    "act_timestamp": 1576480759864,
    "action": 26,
    "cmd_line": "\\??\\C:\\Windows\\system32\\conhost.exe 0xffffffff",
    "guid": "45af94911fb911ea827300270e098ff0",
    "md5": "d5669294f78a7d48c318ef22d5685ba7",
    "name": "conhost.exe",
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\conhost.exe",
    "pid": 1968,
    "sha2": "6bd1f5ab9250206ab3836529299055e272ecaa35a72cbd0230cb20ff1cc30902",
    "proc_id": "45af94901fb911ea827300270e098ff0",
    "proc_name": "gcxvdf.exe"
}
```

I have around 100GB of such jsons stored in s3, in folder structure like year/month/day/hour.
I have to query this data and get results in **milliseconds**. 
query can be like:-

```
select proc_id where name='conhost.exe',
select proc_id where cmd_line contains 'conhost.exe'.
```

I tried using AWS Athena and Redshift but both are giving results around 10-20 seconds. I even tried with Paraquet and orc file formats.

Is there any tool/technology/technique which can be used to query this kind of data and get results in milliseconds.

(Reason for response time to be in milliseconds is because I am developing interactive application.)

Comment: you need a standard indexed rdbms like postgres, with indexes set up appropriately. see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html . 100GB should not be a problem.

Comment: i have read that aws-athena internally uses postgres, hence I didn't explore postgre in more depth.

Comment: You should! Redshift is based on postgres but NO indexes and NO text search. athena is based on presto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve above use case by using presto,hive on aws emr.

With help of hive we can create table on data in s3, and by using presto and hive as a catalog we can query this data.
Found out that Presto on emr is way too faster than compared to aws athena
(strange that athena uses presto internally)

```
 create table in hive:-
        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_table`( 
         `field_name1` datatype,
         `field_name2` datatype,
         `field_name3` datatype
        )
        STORED AS ORC
        LOCATION
          's3://test_data/data/';
        
 query this table in presto:-
        >presto-cli --catalog hive
        >select field_name1 from test_table limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a distributed search system like SOLR or elastic search (I am sure there are others, but those are the ones I am familiar with).

Also worth considering if you are able to reduce your data size at all. Any old or stale date in your 100GB?

Comment: I tried elastic search ..but it gives only max 10k documents in response. for some of my queries results matches millions of documents and to fetch these many documents using scroll/scan in elastic search is slow. so I figured out elastic-search is not an option.

Comment: Does your end user require millions of records in one go? Likely not, although I do not know your use case.